# Compile Java project with packages

Tags: java, compilation

I tried

```
javac -cp 1.jar:2.jar:. myproject.java
```

to compile the entire project but it doesn't work for the packages I have in my project folder.

Can someone show me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the asterisk, which tells `javac` to compile all classes in the package. (But note that it won't recursively search any sub-packages for files).

`javac -cp "1.jar:2.jar" myproject/java/*.java`

`java -cp "1.jar:2.jar" myproject.java.<MainClassHere>`

For this to work your working directory should look like this:

```
.
./1.jar
./2.jar
./myproject
./myproject/java
```

---

**Update:** Also you were using periods to separate directores in your `javac` invocation. It should be `myproject/java/*.java` instead

Comment: javac: invalid flag: src.*
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: Sorry I fixed it. When you list your source files with `javac` you should be using forward slashes to separate directories, not periods.

Comment: also, how do I force the compiler to move all .class files to -d bin directory

Comment: this is what I wrote but not sure if it will work right javac -cp a.jar:src src/*/*.java -d bin/

Comment: No, you can't use the asterisk that way. You can use it as a wildcard in filenames, but not in directory names.

Comment: You need to run `javac -cp a.jar src/myproject/java/*.java -d bin`